# CG Rect Issue - Cannot invoke initializer

Tags: swift

I have fixed the my original issue but I have a new error thats says "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SideBarDelegate'."

I know I am very close to getting this working but for some reason cant figure out why this is happening! Can anybody help?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate  {

var sideBar: SideBar = SideBar()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath:     "locations")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    //sidebar

    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, skateItems: ["All Skate Spots", "Skateparks", "Street Skating"])

    // Passing firebase annotation data

    locationsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        for item in snapshot.children {

            guard let locationData = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }

            let locationValue = locationData.value as! [String: Any]

            var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

            if let lat = locationValue["lat"] as? String {
                // Stored as String
                let lng = Double(locationValue["lng"] as! String)!
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: lng)
            }
            else {
                // Stored as a floating point number
                let lat = locationValue["lat"] as! Double
                let lng = locationValue["lng"] as! Double
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
            }

            let name = locationValue["name"] as! String

            let subtitle = locationValue["subtitle"] as! String

            self.addAnnotation(at: location, name: name, subtitle: subtitle)

        }
    })
}

func addAnnotation(at location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, subtitle: String) {

    // Adding annotation to the map

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

        annotation.title = name

        annotation.subtitle = subtitle

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

}

}

func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {

}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {



}
```

Comment: just add a space between - and 1 -> `-barWidth - 1` or `-barWidth + -1`

Comment: Thanks, however I then get another issue, which I have posted above as updated code

Comment: Don't post screen shots ! Post your code.

Comment: Sorry will do that now

Comment: please you should read the section of the site https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You may post only the code related to the question you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I am new, I will do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a delegate is declared as a weak optional (that solves the *not initialized* error)

```
weak var delegate: SideBarDelegate?
```

And is always called with optional chaining which does nothing if the delegate is not set.

For example

```
delegate?.sideBarWillClose?()
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That was extremely helpful!

Comment: Vardian, I have a new issue! Could you possibly help with this?

Comment: Who is *Vardian*? Do not mess up the question by changing the content. Now the body of the question has nothing to do with the subject. Ask a new question. `does not conform to protocol` means you have to implement the required methods of the protocol.

Comment: I meant Vadian...apologies?!